# How do I export a schema with all data to my local instance on my PC (Oracle XE)

Tags: database, oracle, impdp, expdp

The Server is Oracle 11g 11.2.0.4.0
The local instance of my Oracle is "Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0"

I want to export the schema called "AlphaTest" and all it's associated triggers, tables, views, packages, etc

and import that to my local instance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have two databases available so I'll try to do it on my local 11gXE.

First, connect as privileged user (SYS), check which directories I have and grant required privileges to users I'll export & import:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> desc dba_directories
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 OWNER                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DIRECTORY_NAME                            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DIRECTORY_PATH                                     VARCHAR2(4000)

SQL> col directory_name format a15
SQL> col directory_path format a60
SQL> select directory_name, directory_path from dba_directories;

DIRECTORY_NAME  DIRECTORY_PATH
--------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
TEST_DIR        c:\
EXT_DIR         c:\temp
ORACLECLRDIR    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\clr
DATA_PUMP_DIR   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle/admin/xe/dpdump/
XMLDIR          C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\xml
ORACLE_OCM_CONF C:\ADE\aime_xe28\oracle/ccr/state
IG_DIR


6 rows selected.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

If I didn't have any directory, I'd create it as

```
SQL> create directory brisime_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory brisime_Dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

and continue with ...

### ... Export:

```
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

C:\Temp>expdp scott/tiger file=scott.dmp directory=ext_dir

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Vel 3 22:17:53 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Legacy Mode Active due to the following parameters:
Legacy Mode Parameter: "file=scott.dmp" Location: Command Line, Replaced with: "dumpfile=scott.dmp"
Legacy Mode has set reuse_dumpfiles=true parameter.
Starting "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  scott/******** dumpfile=scott.dmp directory=ext_dir reuse_dumpfiles=true
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 320 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
. . exported "SCOTT"."ABC"                               6.867 KB       6 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."DEPT"                              5.929 KB       4 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."DUMMY"                             5.007 KB       1 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."EMP"                               8.562 KB      14 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."SALGRADE"                          5.859 KB       5 rows
. . exported "SCOTT"."BONUS"                                 0 KB       0 rows
Master table "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SCOTT.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  C:\TEMP\SCOTT.DMP
Job "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at 22:18:02


C:\Temp>
```

### Import:

use system account to perform it. REMAP_SCHEMA will create a new_user for you and do the import:

```
C:\Temp>impdp system/pwd file=scott.dmp directory=ext_dir remap_schema=scott:new_user

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Vel 3 22:25:38 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Legacy Mode Active due to the following parameters:
Legacy Mode Parameter: "file=scott.dmp" Location: Command Line, Replaced with: "dumpfile=scott.dmp"
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  system/******** dumpfile=scott.dmp directory=ext_dir remap_schema=scott:new_user
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "NEW_USER"."ABC"                            6.867 KB       6 rows
. . imported "NEW_USER"."DEPT"                           5.929 KB       4 rows
. . imported "NEW_USER"."DUMMY"                          5.007 KB       1 rows
. . imported "NEW_USER"."EMP"                            8.562 KB      14 rows
. . imported "NEW_USER"."SALGRADE"                       5.859 KB       5 rows
. . imported "NEW_USER"."BONUS"                              0 KB       0 rows
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at 22:25:41


C:\Temp>
```

### Check ...

... whether everything is there:

```
C:\Temp>sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pon Vel 3 22:30:14 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> alter user new_user identified by new_pwd;

User altered.

SQL> connect new_user/new_pwd
Connected.
SQL> select * From tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
ABC                            TABLE
BONUS                          TABLE
DEPT                           TABLE
DUMMY                          TABLE
EMP                            TABLE
SALGRADE                       TABLE
V_EMP_DEPT                     VIEW

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.

Comment: is there a way to do this without exporting to a directory on the server? like export it and import it directly to the local instance

Comment: Yes; search for NETWORK_LINK, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-0871E56B-07EB-43B3-91DA-D1F457CF6182.htm#SUTIL919. Walkthrough https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-use-data-pump-network-mode-step-by-step/